# How can I set a CSS property on the html element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I set a CSS property on the html element with jQuery?

I'm trying to do something like...

```
$('html').css({'background': 'url(/images/bg.png) top center'})
```

EDIT: For those that will ask why not just set it on the body or some other work around, this needs to be set like this as it fixes a webkit bug in iOS 4

EDIT 2: I guess this is doing what it should already. It must be something with the finicky bug that is causing this to act differently then when I set it via external CSS, strange

Comment: Isn't `background` CSS properties supposed to go in `body` rather than `html`?

Comment: Try setting it on the body, not the html!

Comment: read edit! i asked this question for a reason!

Comment: I use styles (including background) on `<html>` all the time, have no idea what these guys are talking about. This [should already work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/sXhpt/), your image path is probably wrong.

Comment: @Fancy: how about setting it with `html,body`?

Comment: @Fancy - so you're saying that code doesn't work? Your edit says it "needs to be set like this as it fixes a webkit bug" - if it fixes the bug then what's the problem? The syntax looks fine, and as Wesley said `background` can work with `html`. The [w3 recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#background) is to set the `background` on the `body` element, but it doesn't say you can't apply it to `html`.

Comment: @nnnnnn read second edit, i guess this bug is just really annoying, i don't get why it would be different but...

Comment: @fancy, why dance all around this issue?  You posted valid code that should be working and talk about working around a Webkit bug.  Please, for the readers' benefit, explain this Webkit bug so we can get to the root of the issue.

Comment: @Sparky672, It's a bug that causes page flicker during css animations. I fixed it to the point where only the background flickers to white, or what the html bg is set to. The problem is that this is a one page application so if the bg changes I need change the html bg without doing a page reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply like that:

`$('html').css('background', 'url(/images/bg.png) top center')`

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing syntactically incorrect about your jQuery code.

EDIT: Try setting it to the body and the html:

```
$('html, body').css({'background': 'url(/images/bg.png) top center'})
```

If you're only doing one change, it's best to use the singular form:

```
$('html, body').css('background', 'url(/images/bg.png) top center')
```

Comment: Those are two different elements, and both can have backgrounds. There's no reason you can't style the `<html>` element.

Comment: Clearly it's not working for him.  Hence the suggestion to try setting both `html` and `body`.  I don't see a need to vote this down.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
$('theSelector').css('background', 'url(/images/bg.png) top center');
```

For the `theSelector` portion you can use the most appropriate jQuery selector for your situation

- http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/